# ajax and SQL display database value on appended row

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

Im starting to learn ajax to update my SQL without refreshing the page, I have successfully got the delete function to work, as well as adding a new row, however it doesn't display the right information. How can I get the same values I do in PHP with ajax? My ajax curaccid doesnt display any html either when a new row is added.. Ive been looking at other posts for hours but cant seem to understand how to implement others responses into my situation,

I really do appreciate the help, this is something ive been wanting to learn so thank you for your time!

Html:

```
     <form  method="post" >
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>

<tr style="background-color:#F9F9F9; height:10px !important;"> 
<td style="width: 80%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;" ><?php include ("components/hourincome.php"); ?> 
 <span style="float:left; padding-left:6px; font-weight:bold;">Hours:</span> <input  style="padding-left:10px;  float:left; margin:0px; width:40px; border: 0px solid black; background-color: Transparent;" name="hours" class="p1" id="hours"/>
</td> 
<td style="width:15%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE; padding-right:5px;" >

<input style="float:left; width:100%; height:20px;" name="wage" id="wage" type="text" placeholder="wage"/>
</td> 

<td style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE; width: 5%;"> 
 <span href="#" id="<?php $row["accid"] ?>" class="addincomerow" style="font-size:14px; width: 30px; color:white; background-color:#51E77C; padding: 5px; border: 0px solid white; text-decoration:none !important;">
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px; "><div class=" clickable-clear">add</div></i>  
 </span>

</td> 
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

My ajax:

```
 $(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.addincomerow',function(){
        var curaccid= $(this).attr('id');
        var $ele = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'components/sql/insertincome.php',
            data:{'newaccid':curaccid},
            success: 
            function(data){
            $(".toprow" + curaccid).append(
                    '<tr style="" id="row' + curaccid + '">\n\
                <td style="width: 30%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;">\n\
                <span style=" font-size:10px;">(tet$/hr )</span>\n\
                <input id="' + curaccid + '" value="' + curaccid + '" style="float:left; margin:0px; width:40px; border: 0px solid black; background-color: Transparent;" name="newaccid" readonly /></td>\n\
                <td style=" width: 50%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;"> $12 </td>\n\
                <td style="width: 15%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;"> 31 </td>\n\
                <td style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE; width: 5%;"> <span href="#" id="'+ curaccid +'" class="deleteincomerow" style="text-decoration:none !important;">  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px; "><div class=" clickable-clear">clear</div></i> </span> </td></tr>'
                    );
             }

            });
        });
});
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sqlupdateincome = "INSERT INTO income (username, projectname, hourlywage, totalhours)
VALUES ('John', 'Ochrom Test', '". $_POST['wage'] ."', '". $_POST['hours'] ."')";

if ($conn->query($sqlupdateincome) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
     echo  "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: in ajax request you send only `data:{'newaccid':curaccid},` then in php you trying to get `$_POST['wage']` and `$_POST['hours']` which doesn't exist

Comment: DO NOT BUILD SQL QUERIES BY CONCATENATING USER INPUT INTO STRINGS!  Your application will be wide open to SQL injection. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @GordonM I’m going to change this once the script works

Answer (score 2):

You need to echo the ID

```
id="<?php echo $row["accid"]; ?>"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hey thank you for the response! Im not sure I understand, where is this placed? inside the ajax? Also my SQL information from my database isnt being inserted will this fix that issue? Thank you :]

Comment: That would be your HTML.                                  <span href="#" id="<?php echo $row["accid"]; ?>" class="addincomerow" style="font-size:14px; width: 30px; color:white; background-color:#51E77C; padding: 5px; border: 0px solid white; text-decoration:none !important;">

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
function(data){
            $(".toprow" + curaccid).append(
                    '<tr style="" id="row' + curaccid + '">\n\
                <td style="width: 30%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;">\n\
                <span style=" font-size:10px;">(tet$/hr )</span>\n\
                <input id="' + curaccid + '" value="' + curaccid + '" style="float:left; margin:0px; width:40px; border: 0px solid black; background-color: Transparent;" name="newaccid" readonly /></td>\n\
                <td style=" width: 50%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;"> $12 </td>\n\
                <td style="width: 15%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;"> 31 </td>\n\
                <td style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE; width: 5%;"> <span href="#" id="'+ curaccid +'" class="deleteincomerow" style="text-decoration:none !important;">  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px; "><div class=" clickable-clear">clear</div></i> </span> </td></tr>'
                    );
             }
```

to below format and try whether it will work.

```
function(data){
            $(".toprow" + curaccid).append("<tr><td>John</td><td>Ochrom Test</td><td>"your variable"</td><td>"yourothervariable"</td></tr>"
                    );
             }
```

Comment: The table row is added correctly, its the data that i need to transfer. From my SQL I need to place the $_POST variables inside the table

Comment: set a variable like `varible1=$_POST['wage'];` then use this variable in your table. example below.  `function(data){
            $(".toprow" + curaccid).append("<tr><td>John</td><td>Ochrom Test</td><td>" +variable1+"</td><td>"+variable2+"</td></tr>"
                    );
             }`

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, so here it is for anyone new to learning ajax, because it was a little hard for me to understand.

So PHP and SQL are editing the server, which is why you need to refresh the page to see the new updates. In order to have the page update with the server you need to basically fake it.. (to my understanding) until the page is refreshed again. So when a function is called, you would call the PHP script in the background and the ajax script in the front end to change the html content on the page.

My main problem was getting values from my form to SQL, and getting the values that would be placed into SQL to be "faked" on front end since you cant use $_POST in ajax .. A problem I was not doing is serializing the form information. Inside the data section I had to place this:

```
data:$("#addnewincometable").serialize()
```

In Html, I had to add an Id and method into the form:

```
<form  id="addnewincometable" method="post" >
```

and vualá!

Now the PHP script isnt security protected, so before anyone goes off, this is for learning purposes.

Thank you everyone for your responses you all helped with bits and pieces, I wanted to give an overall answer and my full script to anyone in need.

HTML:

```
<form  id="addnewincometable" method="post" >
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>

<tr style="background-color:#F9F9F9; height:10px !important;"> 
<td style="width: 80%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;" ><?php include ("components/hourincome.php"); ?> 
 <span style="float:left; padding-left:6px; font-weight:bold;">Hours:</span> <input  style="padding-left:10px;  float:left; margin:0px; width:40px; border: 0px solid black; background-color: Transparent;" name="hours" class="p1" id="hours"/>
</td> 
<td style="width:15%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE; padding-right:5px;" >

<input style="float:left; width:100%; height:20px;" name="wage" id="wage" type="text" placeholder="wage"/>
</td> 

<td style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE; width: 5%;"> 
 <span href="#" id="<?php echo $row["accid"]; ?>" class="addincomerow" style="font-size:14px; width: 30px; color:white; background-color:#51E77C; padding: 5px; border: 0px solid white; text-decoration:none !important;">
   <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px; "><div class=" clickable-clear">add</div></i>  
 </span>

</td> 
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$sqlupdateincome = "INSERT INTO income (username, projectname, hourlywage, totalhours)
VALUES ('John', 'Ochrom Test', '". $_POST['wage'] ."', '". $_POST['hours'] ."')";

if ($conn->query($sqlupdateincome) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
     echo  "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close(); ?>
```

AJAX:

```
 $(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.addincomerow',function(){
        var curaccid= $(this).attr('id');
        var $ele = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'components/sql/insertincome.php',
            data:$("#addnewincometable").serialize(),
            success: 
            function(data){
            $(".toprow" + curaccid).append(
                    '<tr style="" id="row' + curaccid + '">\n\
                <td style="width: 30%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;">\n\
                <span style=" font-size:10px;">(' + jQuery("#wage").val() + '$/hr )</span>\n\
                <input id="' + curaccid + '" value="' + curaccid + '" style="float:left; margin:0px; width:40px; border: 0px solid black; background-color: Transparent;" name="newaccid" readonly /></td>\n\
                <td style=" width: 50%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;"> $'+ jQuery("#hours").val() +' Total Hours </td>\n\
                <td style="width: 15%; border-bottom:1px solid #DEDEDE;"> 31 </td>\n\
                <td style = "border-bottom: 1px solid #DEDEDE; width: 5%;"> <span href="#" id="'+ curaccid +'" class="deleteincomerow" style="text-decoration:none !important;">  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px; "><div class=" clickable-clear">clear</div></i> </span> </td></tr>'
                    );
             }

            });
        });
});
```